# Error transforming a vector via Homography matrix - C++ OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have 2 frames of a video stream done by a moving (very slow) camera; after using (through OpenCV) SIFT algorithm and findHomography OpenCv function i have the transformation matrix that describes the movement done by the camera between the 2 frames.
what i would like to do is to find a point of the first frame in the second one:
so my code is :

```
H = findHomography( point1, point2, CV_RANSAC );  //compute the transformation matrix using the
                                       // matching points (the matrix is correct, i checked it)
Mat dstMat(3, 1, H.type());    
vector<Point3f> vec;
Mat srcMat(3, 1, H.type());
vec.push_back(Point3f(Ptx,Pty,-1));   // fill the 3x1 vector with the coordinate
                                         // of the interest point in frame 1
srcMat= Mat(vec).reshape(1).t();     //conversion of vec in Mat (the vector is correct, i checked it)
dstMat = H*srcMat;     //compute the arrival point in frame 2  // ERROR
```

But, where error is written, i receive the following error:
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2)) in gemm, file /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1306/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 711
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-opencv2-2.4.2-1precise-20130312-1306/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:711: error: (-215) type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2) in function gemm

Aborted (core dumped)

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit convoluted. In particular, it is not sure what size entries the `reshape`method, and then the effect of the transpose since you also specified before the size of `srcMat`.

You could try the following:

```
cv::Mat srcMat(3, 1, CV_32F); // Allocate a 3x1 column vector (floating point)

srcMat.at<float>(0,0) = Ptx;
srcMat.at<float>(1,0) = Pty;
srcMat.at<float>(2,0) = -1.0;

dstMat = H * srcMat;  // Perform matrix-vector multiplication
```

Note that you do not really need to allocate `dstMat`beforehand ; it is automatically done by OpenCV.
Yuu should maybe check also for the type of `H`, I am not sure that `cv::findHomography` returns a single or double-precision matrix, in which case you have to replace `float`by `double` and `CV_32F` by `CV_64F`;